# When working with just one observation what would the variance be?

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics, missing-data

I am working with a data set where I am calculating the variance for the variable hours by gender, education group, agegrp (age group) and input.    However, I am running into a situation where there is only one type of cohort and the value for the variance calculation of hours ends up as missing.

But I need a value for this cell for another calculation that I will be doing.

Question:  Is there a value that is a best practice to use in place of the missing variance value?
The data set is below:

[image]

The data after:
[image]

Comment: If there's only one data point, the variance is zero.

Comment: Please say more about the "other calculation" that requires a variance value. This looks like a type of analysis of variance setup in which you really want to be sharing information about underlying variances among all the different combinations of factors rather than relying on calculations of the variance for each individual combination of the factors. What is the question you are trying to answer with your overall analysis?

Comment: I was going to run this table threw small area estimation model.  I was told I need the variance of the variable in question which is hours.

Comment: [Small area estimation](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177010647) typically depends on "borrowing strength" among different but related areas. If that's the case with your downstream analysis, I suspect that the variance estimate that you want would be based on the residual error from an analysis of variance of all those data rather than on individual sample variances for each combination of factors. Check with the person who told you that you need the variance of the hours.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the tip.